# Under what conditions would Ricci tensor have the trace values $(+---)$ and rest 0's?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, curvature

Under what conditions would Ricci tensor have the following values:

$R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ where $\mu \not= \nu$

$R_{00} = 1$

$R_{\mu\nu} = -1$ where $\mu = \nu$ (and non-zero)

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what is this question motivated by? Also, the Ricci tensor can be expressed explicitly via the connection coefficients, so perhaps you can just try to solve for them with the values of the Ricci components you're interested at? Anyway, perhaps if it is clarified what you're trying to achieve it will be easier to provide assistance...

Answer (score 0):

One obvious subset of solutions is the Einstein manifold where the Ricci tensor is proportional to the metric tensor $R_{\mu \nu} = \frac{R}{4} g_{\mu \nu}$. If you then consider a diagonal metric with the signature you want (and with a positive $R$), you get the same property in the Ricci tensor. Some examples of Einstein spacetimes are maximally symmetric spacetimes like dS and AdS.

Other than these, it is perhaps quite a difficult task to find solutions to the Ricci tensor of the form you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. So, are you saying that  maximally symmetric dS spacetime would have a Ricci tensor with the form that I mentioned?

Comment: @physics_2015 yes